# php sending file without extension to email

Tags: php, mysql

I have page where user upload they file to my web server which get save without extension.

for e.g. example.doc will be saved as current time(1234567890) but without extension.

this works OK I dont have this problem.

What i'm having problem is that i like to send the document by email later on to a email address. i like to assign original name including the extension of the file.

All the data is save in my database. name and extension of the.

so for example i like to send this file "1234567890" as example.doc to a email address.

Comment: You should include code / what you've tried.

Comment: alright. you know what to do. What doesn't work?

Comment: thats the thing. I can't thing of how this can be done.

Comment: @PLB I'm try to ignore this. other thing i can thing of is to copy the file temp location rename it and then attache to email and then delete that file.

Comment: @Lalajee Not a bad idea, but if you know what to do where's the problem?

Comment: i was think same line as $location = $file_path.$file_name;header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$orginal_name."\""); // use 'attachment' to force a download
  header("Content-length: ".$file_size);
  header("Content-type: ".$file_type);
  
  readfile( $location );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use phpmailer AddStringAttachment

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial#3.2

Comment: I have decided to use Rmail. Which works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**CODE**

```
  <html>
   <head>
    <title>My First File Sender</title>
   <meta charset="utf8 ">
  </head>
    <body>

    <?php
      if (!isset($_POST["file"]))
       {
         echo '<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br><input type="submit" value="Send File"></form>';
      }else {
       /*
        Settings start here
       */
       $target_dir = "files/";
       $name = "John Doe";
       $email = "johndoe@freemail.net";
       $subject = "New File";
       /*
       Settings end here
      */
       $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
       $uploadOk = 1;
       $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
       $msg = '
       Dear  ' . $name . ',<br>
      A new file has been sent, it will be saved in the uploads file.<br><br>

   Thank you,<br>
   Automated System
    ';
      mail($email,$subject,$msg);
      echo "Thank You.";
      }

     ?>




  </body>
  </html>
```

**HOW IT WORKS**

The browser will check if you have already added a file.

IF NOT:

It will prompt you to select a file.

IF TRUE:

It will upload the files to whatever `$target_dir` equals.

Then send an email to whatever `$email` equals.

The message will probably look like this.

```
Dear John Doe,
A new file has been sent, it will be saved in the uploads file.


Thank you,
Automated System
```